# How to build records from database for use in Highchart

Tags: c#, asp.net, highcharts

I am trying to plot multiple series on Highchart. The record is fetched from a database as shown below:

[image]

How do I build the data into the required format like the one below:

```
    {
        name: 'ACCESS',
        data: [recievedon, referenceprice], [recievedon, referenceprice], [recievedon, referenceprice]
    }, 
    {
        name: 'AFRIPRUD',
        data: [recievedon, referenceprice], [recievedon, referenceprice], [recievedon, referenceprice]
    }, 
    {
        name: 'ETI',
        data: [recievedon, referenceprice], [recievedon, referenceprice], [recievedon, referenceprice]
    }
```

Comment: From the Highcharts point of view your data should be and array of arrays, so it should look like: `data: [ [recievedon, referenceprice],[recievedon, referenceprice], [recievedon, referenceprice] ]`. More info: [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series<area>.data) (you are using 2nd format). Also - remember that data should be sorted in ascending order by x value (**recievedon** it this case).

Comment: @KacperMadej thanks for your comment. I'm actually trying to plot chart with multiple series. Each SECCODE is a series.